# How to evenly distribute string values to index pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with the pandas library and want to evenly pass "list" dict to my dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
df2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
lst = ['hello' , 'hi']
df2['list'] = lst
```

My desired output is:

```
1 hello
2 hello
3 hello
4 hi
5 hi
6 hi
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Pandas and DataFrames, exactly? In the code you shared, `df2` is a list, and `df2['list'] = lst` should throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
import numpy as np

df2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
lst = ['hello' , 'hi']
df2['list'] = np.repeat(lst, len(df2) // 2)
```

Comment: Hello I came back with another question, what shall I do if I have 3 elements inside lst

Comment: you should post a new question so that others can benefit from your previous and new ones.